# onAfterElementSave and new elements

Tags: plugin-development, custom-fieldtype

I have a field type that needs to do some processing, based on the data in the element it belongs to, when an element (entry, category, user, etc) is saved, and save it to the field. I'm hooking into `onAfterElementSave` and my code (simplified) is as follow:

```
public function onAfterElementSave()
{
    $fieldHandle = $this->model->handle;
    $elementId = $this->element->id;
    $elementType = $this->element->getElementType();
    $elementLocale = $this->element->locale;

    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria($elementType);
    $criteria->id = $elementId;
    $criteria->locale = $elementLocale; 
    $element = $criteria->first();

    if ($element!==null) {
        $myData = $element->title; // just an example
        if ($this->element->$fieldHandle != $myData) {
            $newData = array($fieldHandle => $myData);
            $element->setContent($newData);
            craft()->elements->saveElement($element);
        }
    } 
}
```

This works fine on existing entries, but when I create new entries, $element is null, so the field isn't updated.

What's going on and how can I fix this? Isn't onAfterElementSave actually after element save? :)

Comment: Looking at the `ElementsService` it looks like the element have not yet gotten an id, so you won't get any hits searching for it with the ElementCriteria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using it like this:

```
public function onAfterElementSave()
{
    $fieldHandle = $this->model->handle;
    if ($this->element!==null) {
        $myData = $this->element->title; // just an example
        if ($this->element->$fieldHandle != $myData) {
            $this->element->getContent()->setAttribute($fieldHandle, $myData);
            craft()->elements->saveElement($this->element);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Bob, that solved it for me. At some point I was sure that $this->element was read-only or something, so I went for the long way around, with the ElementCriteria.

Comment: What's the equivalent for `$this->model->handle` in Craft 3? I can't seem to find a way to obtain the handle.

Comment: Just `$this->handle`